# could not update currently locked vb.net error

Tags: vb.net, sql-insert

I want to Insert 2 different data in 2 different `table of ms-access`.

And it shows this error.

[image]

I have a code like this:

```
try
 dim sql1,sql2 as string
 sql1 = "INSERT INTO table1(something)VALUES(something)"
 cmd = new oledbcommand(sql1, connection)
 cmd.executenoquery()

 sql2 = "INSERT INTO table2(something)VALUES(something)"
 cmd2 = new oledbcommand(sql2, connection)
 cmd2.executenoquery()
catch ex as exception
  msgbox(ex.tostring())

(where these cmd1,cmd2 are defined in controlModule.)
```

so,what should I do ?

Any help is appreciated. Thank You

Comment: Do you have one of those tables opened in MS-Access in desing mode?

Comment: @Steve No, I don't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think closing the connection fixes the issue, best by using the `Using`-statement:

```
try
    Using con As OleDbConnection = GetConnection() ' or New OlebConnection(...)
        Using cmd = con.CreateCommand()
            cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO table1(something)VALUES(@something)"
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@something", something)
            con.Open()
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        End Using
    End Using 

    Using con As OleDbConnection = GetConnection()
        Using cmd = con.CreateCommand()
            cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO table2(something)VALUES(@something)"
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@something", something)
            con.Open()
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        End Using
    End Using 
Catch ex As Exception
    msgbox(ex.tostring())
End Try
```

Comment: Thanks, @Tim Schmelter.  It helped me.

Answer (score 0):

This is a concurrency issue. Because some other part of your code or MS Access itself accesses the database at the same time. 
The fact is that you're not closing the connection after it's use. So the 2nd call should fail with that exception. Instead, you should wrap your disposables - e.g. the OleDbConnection, commands, etc. - in a using statement. That way, the connection will be closed, even if an exception occur:

```
    Using con As New OleDbConnection, cmd1 As OleDbCommand = con.CreateCommand, cmd2 As OleDbCommand = con.CreateCommand()
        cmd1.CommandText = "INSERT INTO table1(something)VALUES(something)"
        cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery()

        cmd2.CommandText = "INSERT INTO table2(something)VALUES(something)"
        cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery()
    End Using
```